# Datanucleus mongodb references

Tags: mongodb, orm, datanucleus

Can I fetch fields by DBRef?
I have to separate collection mapped to:

```
@PersistenceCapable(table = "group")
public class MyGroup
{
    @PrimaryKey
    @Persistent(valueStrategy = IdGeneratorStrategy.IDENTITY, column = "_id")
    private String id;
    private String name;
    private Person person;

    // getters/setters
    ...
}

@PersistenceCapable(table = "people")
public class Person
{
    @PrimaryKey
    @Persistent(valueStrategy = IdGeneratorStrategy.IDENTITY, column = "_id")
    private String id;
    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;

    // getters/setters
    ...
}
```

I'd like to get person name (currently I got person as null):

```
MyGroup myGroup = persistenceManager.getObjectById(MyGroup.class, "5230a918ac8c95fd3d9a3dfa")
myGroup.getPerson().getFirstName();
```

and perform queries:

```
Query query = persistenceManager.newQuery(MyGroup.class);
query.setFilter("persone.firstName == \"Tester\"");
```

Comment: Firstly, invalid JDOQL quoted. Secondly have you tried it (with valid JDOQL)?

Comment: @NeilStockton No, as I get person = null.

Comment: So why not start by updating your question with the valid JDOQL that you tried, and then put what MongoDB query it invoked (in the log)

Comment: @NeilStockton The issue is not query. If I just fetch the object by Id I got the person field null. I expect to get  Person object.

Comment: If the issue is not the query then remove that from the question and put the getObjectById and the result, and then look in the log and see if it is in the database, and see the MongoDB query issued to retrieve it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

DataNucleus doesn't support DBRef on MongoDB datastore:
http://www.datanucleus.org/servlet/forum/viewthread_thread,7924#38188